# Unable to execute script using ansible shell module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an ansible script to execute a script using the shell module, and it completes the ansible playbook with a status of 'SUCCESS', but the script has not been executed for some reason.

Playbook:

```
- hosts: '{{ hosts }}'
  tasks:
  - name: Copy a dummy file to /tmp folder
    command: "cp /apps/tomcat-web/LICENSE /tmp/LICENSE-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}"

  - name: Start email service
    shell: ./start.sh >> /tmp/log.txt
    args:
      chdir: /email-service/
```

Console Output:

```
+ ansible-playbook deploy/test-ansible.yml --extra-vars hosts=mut

PLAY [mut] ****************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [ftp2]

TASK [Copy a dummy file to /tmp folder] ****************************************
changed: [ftp2]

TASK [Start email service] *****************************************************
changed: [ftp2]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ftp2                   : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   

Finished: SUCCESS
```

The first step in the playbook (creating a license file) is being done properly. But the second step (executing start.sh) is not being done. Can anyone explain? Will be much appreciated.

Note: The script's full path is /email-service/start.sh
Thanks!

Comment: Execute playbook with `-vvv` to see what's happening with `start.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, see the new output below (comments for Xiong)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TASK [Start email service] *****************************************************
> changed: [ftp2]
> ```

It certainly looks like your script is being run.  However, perhaps it is not running *successfully*?

Three suggestions for helping debug it:

1. Invoke ansible with more verbosity (more `-v`s).
2. Redirect stderr into your log file as well (`./start.sh >> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1`)
3. Add `set -x` into your script so that it prints out every command it runs.

You may also find `set -euo pipefail` useful in creating a well-behaved shell script that correctly exits with a failure code when encountering an error in its commands.

---

Separately from all of that, you should **not** be using `command` to copy a file; use [the `copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) instead:

```
  - name: Copy a dummy file to /tmp folder
    copy:
      src: /apps/tomcat-web/LICENSE
      dest: /tmp/LICENSE-{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}
      remote_src: yes
```

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and did #1 and 2. But I don't think the additional output is of much help. See below:changed: [ftp2] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./start.sh >> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1", "delta": "0:00:00.002725", "end": "2016-09-21 15:59:12.554926", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "./start.sh >> /tmp/log.txt 2>&1", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": "/email-service/", "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-09-21 15:59:12.552201", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []} SUCCESS

Comment: The log file didn't get any new entries. But when I introduced an intentional error in the playbook, it does go to the log file now. Also, I am unable to understand how to introduce set -x and set -euo pipefail in the command. Can you tell me where I should be adding it?

Comment: Put those right at the top of the script, just below the hashbang, as the first command you execute.